# Rails: Obtain root_url in environments file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, helper, host

Helper methods in rails automatically detect the root url of the application. For example, `user_signup_url` automatically uses `mydoimain.com/user_signup`

However, in my environments/production.rb, I have to manually set my host.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }
```

Is there a way of having this set automatically? Something like the following perhaps:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ROOT_URL }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that user_signup_url does not automatically know or care about the domain -- its url is "/user_signup".

Comment: Having the same need. Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the host is "guessed" from the incoming request. That's why it is accessible in your controllers, and in your views. However, there is no request object at the mailer level, so that's why you have to be verbose in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Set a constant somewhere global, exactly like you described. Put it somewhere in the top of `application.rb`, or perhaps a different value in each of the development environment files?

Or, perhaps you could make a `Constants` class with that particular constant declared inside? (Your call would be `Constants::ROOT_URL`.)

Or, set an environment variable in your shell before Rails is started and access it with `ENV['ROOT_URL']`

The other answer mentions taht `_path` helpers don't need the domain name. This is true -- but I am not sure how the `_url` helpers work, as they are supposed to give you a full URI I think? You might want to investigate how the `_url` helpers work.